# Can "crawl" be used as a noun?

Tags: word-usage

> She fell to the floor, so her fourth step wasn't a step, but a crawl.

Can *crawl* be used this way? If not, what's the closest alternative?

Comment: Of course it can. I can go for a walk, or a run, or for a crawl.

Comment: Yes.  A "Pub Crawl" seems to be the most common usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crawl?a=british):

> crawl (*noun*) `movement` a very slow speed : *Traffic moved forward at a crawl.*

So yes, that usage is fine.